# Error establishing a database connection while accessing azure web app

Tags: azure, web-applications, cleardb

**The problem is, we have hosted two web apps in standard pricing mode of  two azure accounts. Both apps are getting down continuously for sometimes and automatically recovers back. NOW BOTH APPS ARE DOWN AND NOT RECOVERING BACK.

The error usually getting is 
Error establishing a database connection**

The problem was occuring several times a day and becomes down for 10 to 15 minutes. NOW IT IS PERMANENTLY DOWN.

It is affecting our business critically. So please help us immediately.
YOUR HELP ON THIS PROBLEM IS HIGHLY APPRECIATED.

Answer (score 0):

We've been having the same problem today. Our databases are hosted with ClearDB at this endpoint azure-east-a and they've been failing all day. Quick fix was to move all our databases to a new instance hosted in Aus-SouthEast. Our sites are back up now but the Aus-East instance is still having troubles.

Answer (score 0):

Having Issue too:

Getting Error Message:

Error establishing a database connection

Even through there is no database.

Just the standard your app had been created web page that Azure put in there.

This been happening the last few days.

Then I notice some times that the original App Service plan was changed to a newly created one that I did not made.

When looking for the app service plan in Azure it does not show up.

There is also no option in Web site settings to change service plan.

That link was gone.